# Pandas Rolling_std with Window using all previous row counts

Tags: python, windows, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the rolling_std for daily returns, using all records previous to the current row. How do i set the window to use the rolling count of the rows? For example: on `04-04`. I want to use all rows to calculate, on `04-01` I want to use all rows with date less than `04-01`.

```
Date        Daily       Std
4/4/2016    -0.003087335    ?
4/1/2016    0.006480923 ?
3/31/2016   -0.001553158    ?
3/30/2016   0.004351748 ?
3/29/2016   0.009234222 ?
```

Comment: you probably want `expanding()` rather than `rolling()` and also need to sort to get things in ascending date order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With pandas 0.18, use the `Rolling` object. This is a 2-day rolling std:

```
df.rolling(2).std()
```

With prior version, the call would be:

```
df.rolling_std(2)
```

If the goal is to get the function applied from the beginning of the DataFrame down to the current line, then the object to use is `Expanding`:

```
df.expanding().std()
```

Comment: I want the number of days of rolling to be dynamic based on the number of previous records. So on 4-4 should have 5 rows, on 4-1 should use 4 rows, on 3-31 should use 3 rows.

Comment: also need to sort b/c dates are currently reversed compared to what OP is asking for.  expanding only goes in one direction, I believe.

Comment: Buzz light year to the rescue, didn't realize there was such a simple built in functionality, thank you.